# Subscription to the JIRA filter for the reporter and team leader

Tags: jira, tracking, task-management

I need to set up a filter subscription for sending a list of issues that are `not in (Resolved, Closed) AND assignee is EMPTY` to reporters and to their team leaders. So I need to find any issues for every possible reporter and send that list (if it's not empty) to said reporter and to the reporter's team leader. How can I do that (if it's possible)? If there are no options with native JIRA features, maybe there are some third-party solutions?

Comment: Do you mean: status not in (Closed,Resolved) and reporter=currentUser() and assignee is EMPTY   ? That would show what you need to the reporter when they opened the filter. The team leader would be a different filter.

Comment: Why don't you set your jira to have the assignee field mandatory? If the real assignee is unknown you assign it to the person who has to find the correct person?

Comment: @lnjuanj, Yes, it should work for the reporter, but still there is no known solution for team leader

Comment: Team leader is the same as Project Lead or Component Lead? I only see Team Leader in my Tempo plugin. Please clarify about it. BTW, do you have the script runner plugin?

Comment: Any news about this? Could you finally find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

1. Save the filter @lnjuanj proposed and share to all, show this on a public dashboard, each team member can have a tab open with the dashboard
2. Get each team to create an equivalent search with assignee the team lead, show this Filter Result on a team dashboard